# Windows home premium

Tags: windows-7, windows

I keep getting a java script alert popup box that says Hello new user that I must type OK to..  How can I stop it from appearing?  I have tried asking that it be illiminated but doen't help.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?  Are you doing anything while it pops up (web browsing, in a specific program, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

When you next get that pop up, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>.  After Task Manager Pops up, you should see the window under Applications or Processes.  Right-Click, and select Open File Location.  The folder will open up, and show you what the file is, and where it is located.

Just to be safe, I wouldn't just delete it outright.  It sounds like a test script, but some research would be best before doing so.  If you can post that screen shot, with the file name, that would help greatly.